# Drupal Content Access Issues

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, access-control

I just recently tried installing the Access Content Module to Drupal 5. The module didn't work correctly and I can not uninstall the module without getting an Internal Server Error.

Since I'm struck with the module I now have to try to use it.

Now I'm getting this error when an anonymous user views a page with a specific field_name that is connected to a content type that I can't grant full access to.

> user warning: Column 'nid' in where clause is ambiguous query: SELECT
>   title FROM node INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = n.nid WHERE
>   (na.grant_view >= 1 AND ((na.gid = 0 AND na.realm = 'all') OR (na.gid
>   = 1 AND na.realm = 'content_access_rid'))) AND ( nid=7626) in /includes/database.mysql.inc on line 174.

The nid=7626 is referring to a field_name that is connected to the content type.

When I try and grant access to the content type I get an Internal Server Error. 
Now my logs are saying that my database schema is not up to date. 
I may have accidentally placed a later version of this module on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible that I accidentally installed a newer version of the module?

Comment: If you are having trouble with a module, the best place to post your problem is in the module's issue queue on drupal.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually turn off the module in the MySQL table in your Drupal db called system.
Browse the table and you should see the module names somewhere and an enabled flag.  Remember to run update.php after you turn it off.
Even if you choose to keep the module running update.php will apply module schema changes that have not been applied, and thus fix the issue.